# Setting autossh tunnels

Tags: linux, ssh, ssh-tunneling, autossh

We have server with installed autossh

Number of tunnels approximately 20

Today we add new tunnel, but it doesn't work.

If we switch positioning of `user@server.com` and `user@servernew.com`, the one that comes first will work, the other not.

For example

```
-o GatewayPorts .........................................................

-o GatewayPorts .........................................................

-o GatewayPorts .........................................................

-o GatewayPorts=yes -i /home/user/.ssh/user -NL 192.168.0.1:80:5.6.7.8:80 user@server.com # work fine

-o GatewayPorts=yes -i /home/user/.ssh/user -NL 192.168.0.2:80:1.2.3.4:80 user@servernew.com # not work
```

if we change line

```
-o GatewayPorts .........................................................

-o GatewayPorts .........................................................

-o GatewayPorts .........................................................

-o GatewayPorts=yes -i /home/user/.ssh/user -NL 192.168.0.2:80:1.2.3.4:80 user@servernew.com # work fine

-o GatewayPorts=yes -i /home/user/.ssh/user -NL 192.168.0.1:80:5.6.7.8:80 user@server.com # not work
```

In /var/log we have no error.

When we check listen port using command `netstat -tan | grep LISTEN`

Last tunnel does not show up.

May this be a connection limit?

Comment: I wolud try to connect manually to the connection that did not work after startup of autossh is finished.

Comment: Add manual ssh tunnel with command ssh -f -N -L 192.168.0.1:80:1.2.3.4:80 tunneluser@1.2.3.4 -p 22 -i /home/user/.ssh/my_key   Work fine, but autoshh does not work if add to /etc/autossh.hosts

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem.

Instead configuration file /etc/autossh.hosts added to /etc/rc.local the following line:

```
autossh -fNL 192.168.0.1:80:1.2.3.4:80 user@1.2.3.4 -p 22 -i /home/user/.ssh/my_key
```

Tunnel ssh work fine.